# CreateFile/WriteFile api in Delphi XE

Tags: delphi, createfile

We are using the Below code for printing the tickets data in LPT1 port. These code in working fine in Win-7 Delphi-7 Exe but same code is not working on Win-7 Delphi XE.
I've try the solution available in net. but it is not helping me to resolved the issues. Please can you suggested any solution for that.

```
function TdmDisneyCastTrac.SendToParallelPort(pContent : TStringList): boolean;
var
  slPrintLines : TStringList;
  hFile : THandle;
  Overlapped : TOverlapped;
  I : integer;
  bContentPrinted : boolean;
  dw : DWORD;
begin
   slPrintLines := TStringList.Create;
   result := True;
   try
      slPrintLines.AddStrings(pContent);
      FillChar(Overlapped, SizeOf(Overlapped),0);
      I := 0;
      repeat
         hFile := INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
         bContentPrinted := True;
         hFile := CreateFile(PChar('LPT1:'), GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_WRITE, nil, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
         if hFile = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then
            bContentPrinted := False
         else
         begin
            Overlapped.hEvent := CreateEvent(nil, False, False, nil);
            if Overlapped.hEvent = 0 then
               bContentPrinted := False
            else
            begin
               if not WriteFile(hFile, slPrintLines.Text[1], length(slPrintLines.Text), dw, @Overlapped) then
               case WaitForSingleObject(Overlapped.hEvent, 4000) of  // wait 3 seconds
                  WAIT_OBJECT_0 : ;
                  WAIT_TIMEOUT,
                  WAIT_ABANDONED : begin
                                     bContentPrinted := False;
                                     if hFile <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then
                                       CloseHandle(hFile);
                                       if Overlapped.hEvent <> 0 then
                                            CloseHandle(Overlapped.hEvent);
                                   end;
             end;
           end;
          end;
          inc(I);
        until bContentPrinted or (I = 3);
        result := bContentPrinted;
  finally
     slPrintLines.Free;
      if hFile <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then
         CloseHandle(hFile);
      if Overlapped.hEvent <> 0 then
         CloseHandle(Overlapped.hEvent);
   end;
end;
```

Noted:- This is the Win API function.

Comment: Please describe the failure mode

Comment: When you say not working - what do you mean? An error message? Nothing prints? Garbage gets printed? What?

Comment: As an aside, it you pass an empty string list to this function it will die horribly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The obvious change is that Delphi 7 uses ANSI text, and XE uses UTF-16 text. I guess you'll need to convert the text to ANSI explicitly in order to match previous behaviour.

```
var
  ansistr: AnsiString;
....
ansistr := AnsiString(slPrintLines.Text);
```

Then you can send that to the file handle in the same way as you did previously.

There are many other issues in this code but I don't want to perform a complete re-write. This is the main issue that you face.

Before you do anything else you must read Marco Cantù's white paper on [Delphi and Unicode](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/38980). There's no point continuing until you have a good understanding of this major breaking change introduced in Delphi 2009.